# Type of unpacked argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I have the following code:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Print(const char* Text, Args... args)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ArgumentList;
    std::function<void(Args... A)> Unpack = [&] (Args... A)
    {
        auto l = {(ArgumentList.push_back(std::to_string(A)), 0)...};
    };

    Unpack(args...);

    for (auto it = ArgumentList.begin(); it != ArgumentList.end(); ++it)
        std::cout<<*it<<"\n";
}
```

It uses a Lambda to unpack and push each argument into the vector (I used the lambda to avoid recursive empty template functions; I prefer the nested lambda). However, it needs to use `std::to_string(..)` because the vector accepts only strings. Thus when I do:

```
Print("%", "One", "Two", 5);
```

It does not compile because `"One"` and `"Two"` are already literals and `std::to_string` only takes integral types.

How can I figure out what type of "argument" is being passed? I tried:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_literal
{
    enum {value = false};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<TCHAR>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<TCHAR*>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<const TCHAR*>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
struct is_literal<std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>>
{
    enum
    {
        value = true
    };
};
```

But realized I couldn't use it on the argument because it's not a template parameter?

I wanted to do:

```
std::function<void(Args... A)> Unpack = [&] (Args... A)
    {
        auto l = {(ArgumentList.push_back(is_literal<A>() ? A, std::to_string(A)), 0)...};
    };
```

Which tests if it's literal but it's not right. How can I fix it and test if each argument is a literal?

Comment: Why do you need to detect literals in particular? What you want is to detect whether a type can be given in input to [`to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) or not

Comment: Well I thought by detecting if it was literal, I can just choose not to pass it to to_string(). Isn't that the same thing? Both ways I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a version of `to_string` of your own:

```
std::string to_string(const char* s) {
    return s;
}
```

And then change your lambda body to:

```
using namespace std;
auto l = {(ArgumentList.push_back(to_string(A)), 0)...};
```

Edit: Actually, it's probably better to just define your `to_string` inside `std`:

```
namespace std {
    std::string to_string(const char* s) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `using std::to_string`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, I don't think it will work. This can enable ADL, but it's not that useful since where're operating with `const char*` here. Actually, it's probably better to just add your own `to_string` to `std` namespace. @CantChooseUsernames

Comment: :) Thank you @catscradle; I added to_string to the namespace std and it works great! I templated it to use the is_literal and type T so it won't just be const char*, but all the other types of "strings" :)